# Firefox Web Extension bug - Unable to render Highcharts

Tags: javascript, firefox, highcharts, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I believe there's a bug in Firefox addons where Highcharts within web-extensions cannot be rendered.

I'm porting a Chrome extension into Firefox. When you click on the extension icon, the popup window renders some charts using Highcharts dynamically. This works in Chrome & Safari. However, with Firefox, the `tabbrowser.xml at line 5828` (shown below) script becomes unresponsive. If the Highcharts are NOT used, the extension loads fine.

Here's the minimal code (from the github link below) to generate simple HighCharts in my extension. I used this to reproduce the issue. https://github.com/bluechips23/FirefoxTesting

**Libraries Used:**

- JQuery: Version 1.12.4 from https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js
- Highcharts: version 5.0.10 from http://www.highcharts.com/download
- JQuery UI: Version 1.12.1 from https://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.12.1.zip

**Code from extension**

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "AppDebugging",
  "description": "Testing app",
  "version": "2.0.0.0",
  "icons": {
      "16": "16.png",
      "48": "48.png",
      "128": "128.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["browser.js", "eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon4.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Testing App"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

**2. popup.html**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
      <title>Test Popup</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

      <script src="popup.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>

     </head>
    <body>
    <div class='header' id="header">
        <h1 id="banner">TESTING</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="bodyContainer" id="bodyId">
      <div class="container" id="container-0"></div>
      <div class="container" id="container-1"></div>
      <div class="container" id="container-2"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**3. popup.js**

```
    function getCurrentTabUrl(callback) {
      var queryInfo = {
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
      };

      browser.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        var url = tab.url;
        console.assert(typeof url == 'string', 'tab.url should be a string');
        callback(url);
      });
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {    
      document.querySelectorAll('a[href]').forEach(function (el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          browser.tabs.create({
            url: event.target.getAttribute('href')
          });
        });
      });

    getCurrentTabUrl(function(url) {
       generateData();
    });

    var generateData = function() {
       console.debug("inside generate data.....");
       var categoryData = new Array();

       for(var index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
          var category = "Category " + index;
          categoryData.push(category);
       }

       for(var index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
        var positiveData = getRandomArray();
        var negativeData = getRandomArray();
        var neutralData = getRandomArray();

        var containerID = "container-" + index;
        console.debug("Container id : " + containerID);
        createChart(name, categoryData, positiveData, negativeData, neutralData, containerID);
       }
    };

    var getRandomNumber = function(min, max) {
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    };

    var getRandomArray = function() {
       var min = 0;
       var max = 50;
       var myArray = new Array();

       for(var index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        var random = getRandomNumber(min, max);
        myArray.push(parseInt(random));
       }

       return myArray;
    };

    var createChart = function(name, categoryData, positiveData, 
                                negativeData, neutralData, container) {
    var titleString = "Chart " + name;
    var subTitleString = "This is a test";

    Highcharts.chart(container, {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            style: {
                color: '#333'
            },
            backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2"
        },
        title: {
            text: titleString,
            style: {
                color: '#333'
            }
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: subTitleString,
            style: {
                color: '#333',
                fontSize: "15px"
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: categoryData,
            labels: {
                style: {
                    fontSize: "12px"
                }
            },
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Values',
                align: 'high',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '18px',
                }
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '14px',
                }
            },
            tickPositioner: function () {
                var positions = [],
                    tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
                    increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 6);

                if (this.dataMax !== null && this.dataMin !== null) {
                    for (tick; tick - increment <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
                        positions.push(tick);
                    }
                }
                return positions;
            },
            gridLineWidth: 0,
        },

        colors: [
            '#4be8a1', 
            '#ed6764', 
            '#adadad', 
        ],
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointWidth: 5, //width of the column bars irrespective of the chart size
                groupPadding: 0.1,
                pointPadding: 0
            },
            column: {
                colorByPoint: true
            },
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            shadow: true,
            useHTML: true,
            shared: true,
            backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Positive',
            data: positiveData

        }, {
            name: 'Negative',
            data: negativeData

        }, {
            name: 'Neutral',
            data: neutralData
        }]
       });

     };});
```

**Here's the full error stack on debugger:**

```
Error: Script terminated by timeout at:
handleEvent@chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml:5828:1
_handleDOMChange@chrome://extensions/content/ext-browser-content.js:203:7
  tabbrowser.xml:5828:1
NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE: Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIMessageSender.sendAsyncMessage]  ext-browser-content.js:213
```

**Here's the tabbrowser.xml:5828:**

```
<method name="handleEvent">
    <parameter name="aEvent"/>
    <body><![CDATA[   // This switch statement throws error.
      switch (aEvent.type) {
        case "load":
          this.updateVisibility();
          TabsInTitlebar.init();
          break;
        case "resize":
          if (aEvent.target != window)
            break;

          TabsInTitlebar.updateAppearance();
          ....
  </method>
```

**Here's the code at ext-browser-content.js:203**

```
_handleDOMChange(detail) {
    let doc = content.document;

    .... [truncated code]....
      // LINE BELOW THROWS ERROR
      contentViewer.getContentSizeConstrained(this.maxWidth * ratio,
                                              this.maxHeight * ratio,
                                              w, h);

      let width = Math.ceil(w.value / ratio);
      let height = Math.ceil(h.value / ratio);

      result = {width, height, detail};
    }

    sendAsyncMessage("Extension:BrowserResized", result);
  },
};
```

Comment: if you think it's a [bug post it here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues) or ask [a question to support](http://www.highcharts.com/support)

Comment: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6547